# Renewal Limit Theorem - Proof by Krengel

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, renewal-processes

I'm actually working through the Renewal Limit Theorem Proof from *"Einführung in die Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie und Statistik" by Ulrich Krengel* and having problems to understand the first step, everything else is fine.

He defines:
$f_m := f_{jj}^{(m)} = $ Probability of reaching state j for the first time again after time m

$p_{jj}^{(n)} := $ Probability of reaching state j again after time n

$u_n := p_{jj}^{(n)} = \sum_{m=1}^n {f_m u_{n-m}}$

$\lambda := \limsup u_{n_k}$

For a sequence $n_k \rightarrow \infty$ and $u_{n_k} \rightarrow \lambda$ and for every $m \geq 1$ there is:
$$\lambda = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} u_{n_k} = \lim_k(f_m u_{n_{k-m}}+\sum_{1\leq s\leq n_k, s\neq m}{f_s u_{n_{k-s}}}) \leq \liminf_k(f_m u_{n_{k-m}}) +\limsup_k (\sum_{1\leq s\leq n_k, s\neq m}{f_s u_{n_{k-s}}})$$

I don't really understand why he sets $\lambda = \limsup u_{n_k} = \lim_k u_{n_k}$ and later uses a sum of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ which is $\leq$ than the $\lim$ itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.